# Progresso das medalhas

Tags: novo-recurso, status-pronto, medalhas

Há algum outro lugar onde posso ver o progresso para conseguir as medalhas?

Por exemplo na página [Estatísticas de análise](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats), ao passar o mouse no número de análises que você fez, aparece um ToolTip com o progresso de algumas medalhas.

Seria interessante se pudesse ver o progresso de todas as medalhas, por exemplo, quantos votos ainda faltam pra conseguir a medalha [Espírito Esportivo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/sportsmanship).

Comment: Você pode usar o data explorer para  fazer consultas nas informações dos sites da SE. Seria bacana fazer um 'pergunta' para juntar as consultas com o progresso das medalhas que o SOpt não mostra como padrão. Como por exemplo é a de [comentários com rank de 5](http://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/947/my-comment-score-distribution)

Comment: O que o @perdeu sugeriu de fazermos é algo assim: [Interesting queries on Data Explorer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/49943/229289), apesar de que eu acho essa proposta de progresso mais interessante do que aquele monte de query.

Comment: Já deve ter uma negação para isto no MSE. Provavelmente facilitaria o pessoal brincar com o sistema. Fica bem tentador. Pode até ser benéfico mas pode ser maléfico. É como porte de arma. Qual causa mais mal? Em geral a resposta é não permitir que a pessoa não tenha o direito a algo que pode trazer problemas, mesmo que eventualmente possa trazer uma solução.

Comment: A negação que o @bigown menciona é: algumas medalhas são propositalmente obscuras de acompanhar o progresso pois isso vai estragar a surpresa. E o efeito surpresa é `[status-by-design]`. (citação necessária, mas tenho certeza que é isso)